# Latin plurals when talking about fallacies

Tags: latin

I have read multiple questions on this site on Latin plurals, and I’ve learned that you can use both English plurals and Latin plurals with words which originate from Latin (e.g. *referendum* - *referenda*/​*referendums*). I however have a somewhat different question:

An example - When reading a text full of fallacies, like for example the argument from ignorance - *argumentum ad ignorantiam*, you often need to use plural forms to show that a text is ridden with them. How do you pluralize these types of Latin “word groups”?

If I extrapolate the rules which I have read from the other questions on the site, it would be (taking the argument from ignorance for example) both *argumentum ad ignorantiams* (or something similar) and *argumenta ad ignorantias* (*argumentum* is neutral, so the plural is *argumenta*, and *ignorantiam* is feminine accusative because of the preposition *ad*, so it becomes feminine accusative plural which is -*as*). However, the first form just seems totally wrong. Is this still legitimate? Or would the only option in these cases be correct Latin plurals?

P.S. I know you all probably think “why don’t you just say arguments from ignorance”, but I feel this could come in useful in other cases, for example in legal terminology.

Comment: The plural of any neuter Latin noun (including the ones that end in _-um_) is the same noun stem ending in _-a_. This is true whether it's subject or object; neuter nouns don't distinguish. So _Argumenta_. Nothing else has to be changed, since they're just prepositional phrases and don't have to agree in number with anything.

Comment: http://www.epicure.demon.co.uk/latinlesson.html

Comment: @JohnLawler: Exactly. Note that some neuter plurals end on *-ia*.

Comment: @JohnLawler I didn't see that, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Personally, If I had to use the Latin, I would go with "arguments *ad ignorantiams*". Using Latin only really flies when you are using stock phrases, or if you are well schooled in Latin, writing to those well schooled in Latin (not very likely these days). Otherwise, it is the very definition of pretentious.

Comment: @Lucas, please take a look at tchrist's first comment to my answer---"arguments _ad ignorantiams_" makes no more sense than "mothers-in-laws" or "courts martials." If you want to go down that route, it has to be "arguments _ad ignorantiam_" as suggested by Mitch in his answer.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić ah - I copied and pasted the Latin from the text above and forgot to delete the 's'.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to go by the Latin, *argumentum ad ignorantiam* pluralises as *argumenta ad ignorantiam* (arguments to ignorance), and similarly *reductio ad absurdum* pluralises as *reductiones ad absurdum* (reductions to absurdity) – the point is that *ad ignorantiam* and *ad absurdum* (and, for that matter, the *principii* in *petitio principii*) serve as adjectival phrases, and are thus indeclinable in Latin.

Comment: This is correct, and I highly recommend using the Latin plurals with these Latin terms; if you're afraid of Latin, you can always revert to "argument from ignorance".

Comment: I don’t know why anyone would ever want to inflect each separate word in the phrase instead of the head noun only.  After all, we don’t talk about *mothers-in-laws* nor *ladies-in-waitings.* Even an *amicus curiae* becomes several *amici curiae*, not *amicus curiarum*. And don’t get be started on *casus  belli*.

Comment: So this is correct _Latin_ grammar. What is accepted practice in English?

Comment: Either use the Latin plural, or try to treat the whole phrase as a unit and apply the regular English pluralisation. Whilst the English plural is sometimes preferable (e.g., _octopuses_ instead of _octopodes_), the Latin plural is probably the less clunky option here.

Comment: Details about Latin noun endings [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/LatinNouns.pdf); Latin verbs [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/LatinVerbs.pdf).

Comment: It should probably be mentioned that if your Latin borrowing _isn't_ a noun or nominal phrase in Latin (e.g., _non sequitur_), then you _must_ use the English pluralisation.

Comment: @Mitch Accepted practice in English is to use English phrases not Latin ones. Leave those for the brie-and-chablising monsignors.

Comment: Or for us lazy, coffee-swilling mathematicians---_mutatis mutandis_ requires fewer letters to type out than your favourite translation thereof!

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić That it does, that it does.  There are a fair handful of those.  I was just catering to somebody’s anti-élitist sensibilities.

Comment: @tchrist: How dare you speak the bastardized tongues of the provinces!

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is

> ad hominem arguments

or

> arguments ad hominem

or

> argumenta ad hominem

in that order of popularity, because there are no stated rules.

---

To explain, first the Latin.

The plural of the stand alone 'argumentum' in English follows that **in Latin**:

> argumenta

The plural of 'argumentum ad ...' **in Latin** is

> argumenta ad ...

the noun is properly (for Latin) the thing pluralized.

---

Now let's turn to English. A foreign phrase is often declined by the borrowers in the know exactly as in the original language. Depending on the language, the later users of the phrase may or may not be proficient in the grammar of the original, and usually it gets analyzed in as natural way as possible in English.

[**The plural of 'argumentum' alone** given in dictionaries is **the same as in Latin**](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&q=definition+argumentum), namely:

> argumenta

That is for the word by itself.

In this example 'argumentum' is easily recognizable in English as 'argument', so the phrase is often given in mixed English/Latin as 'argument ad hominem' or 'an ad hominem argument'. There the plural is given as expected only affecting the noun:

> ad ... arguments

or

> arguments ad ...

or the proper Latin way

> argumenta ad ...

[the English/Latin mix becoming more popular recently for ad hominem and ad populum](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=argumenta+ad+hominem%2Carguments+ad+hominem%2Cad+hominem+arguments%2Cad+populum+arguments%2Carguments+ad+populum%2Carguments+ad+baculum%2Cad+baculum+arguments&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Also, sometimes the qualifier is given as the name of the argument type, e.g. "He used an ad hominem against me", and so there the plural is given as:

> ad hominems

[but again a plural only ever seems to have appeared for 'ad hominem'.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ad+hominems%2Cad+baculums%2Cad+populums%2C+ad+verecundiams&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)
 but this never seems to appear ever in a plural form like 'argumentum ad hominems' (pluralizing the entire Latin phrase as though it were a single thing).

The latter support for the plural is only an argument de facto (by the questionable ngrams) rather than de jure, since dictionaries and style guides seem not to consider the possibility.

Comment: When you apply Occam’s Defacto-Knife™, you find that the opposite of *du jour* is really *du soir*. :)

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn’t try. You can instead say, if you must, 'The text contains many instances of *argumentum ad ignorantiam*.'

Comment: And why not, O down-voter?

Answer (score -1):

To say "argumentum ad ignorantiams" doesn't work at all. It's the argument that needs to be plural. You can't add "s" to a foreign phrase like that to form a plural (although I expect someone will come up with an example to contradict me!). When it's a foreign word rather than a phrase, there's no ambiguity, so you could probably get away with it. (Though I'm not sure if referendum is a good example: many people choose "referendums" because "referenda" isn't necessarily a good Latin plural.)

So when it's a phrase, I'd say you should form the Latin plural correctly for the entire phrase. If you can't expect your audience to cope with that, then you should probably be avoiding the Latin altogether.

Comment: "You can't add 's' to a foreign phrase like that". Proof of this bald assertion, please.

Comment: @ColinFine - Pedantry aside, do you disagree with me? In my answer, I make it clear that I'm open to the possibility that there may be examples where it might work (perhaps with phrases that are well-known enough to be a bit less foreign?). So far I've been unable to come up with an example myself that works well in English.

Comment: Not only can you, but sometimes you have no choice but to, because something that isn't a noun or nominal phrase in the source language, tautologically, has no meaningful plural as a noun or nominal phrase in the source language. For example, the plural of "non sequitur" and even of the absolutely ubiquitous noun "exit" must be "non sequiturs" and "exits" respectively, for the naive, would-be Latin plurals (viz, the third-person plural of those Latin verbal phrases) "non sequuntur" and "exeunt" mean "they don't follow" and "they leave," respectively.

Comment: Exit is by now a good English word. Non sequitur is a good example though. Perhaps we could argue that it has also become English; that the English "non sequitur" is actually the noun that the Latin "non sequitur' implies? Somehow, this makes me want to hyphenate it: non-sequitur, but perhaps that introduces other weirdnesses.

Comment: @Dominic, Your "doesn't work" is a wholly subjective judgment, which others might not share. _I_ would probably not use the Latin tag at all, and if I did I would be showing off and probably would use a Latin plural; but others might well use the form you say doesn't work. You seem to be implying that it's in some way ambiguous, but I don't see it.

Comment: @ColinFine Do you think "argumentum ad ignorantiams" works? Saying that others might use this form doesn't help. Do you think they would be right to do so? I'm not saying it's ambiguous. I'm saying that mixing the grammars of the two languages is ugly enough that many people would find it offending/distracting. As I've argued in another comment, the only mechanism I can see whereby you could use English conventions would be to "adopt" the foreign phrase into English. Otherwise, if you can't form a foreign plural correctly, don't use a foreign phrase.

Comment: I don't know what "works" means. I don't know whether they would be right to do so, because I deny that there is any authority which can decide the question. I agree that it is ugly, and that some would find it offending or distracting. I actually don't think it's very likely that anybody would say it, but they _might_, and in context they might well be understood. So how doesn't it work?

Comment: My criteria for whether language "works" or not cover rather more than "will it be understood?". So for example, while teaching my children to speak "mainstream" English, I'll expect them to say "you are", while "you is" would be perfectly understandable and perhaps correct in other contexts such as dialect or patois. The context of this discussion is "educated" English, otherwise breaking out into Latin would be absurd. So for the target audience, incorrect Latin and other such ugliness probably "doesn't work".